# AVAudioSession does not recognise audio from bluetooth device

Tags: ios, swift, audio, bluetooth, voice-recognition

I am using AVAudioSession to listen to voice input. it works fine for wired headphones but it is not working for connected bluetooth device. Following is the code I am using to set input to bluetooth mic

> ```
> func setupSessionForRecording() {
>     let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
>     do {
>         try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: [.allowBluetooth]) 
>     } catch let error as NSError   {
>         debugPrint("Error in listening "+error.localizedDescription)
>     }
>     var inputsPriority: [(type: String, input: AVAudioSessionPortDescription?)] = [
>         (AVAudioSessionPortLineIn, nil),
>         (AVAudioSessionPortHeadsetMic, nil),
>         (AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP, nil),
>         (AVAudioSessionPortUSBAudio, nil),
>         (AVAudioSessionPortCarAudio, nil),
>         (AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic, nil),
>         ]
>     for availableInput in audioSession.availableInputs! {
>         guard let index = inputsPriority.index(where: { $0.type == availableInput.portType }) else { continue }
>         inputsPriority[index].input = availableInput
>     }
>     guard let input = inputsPriority.filter({ $0.input != nil }).first?.input else {
>         fatalError("No Available Ports For Recording")
>     }
>     do {
>         try audioSession.setPreferredInput(input)
>         try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
>         try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
>         try audioSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(10)
>     } catch {
>         fatalError("Error Setting Up Audio Session")
>     }
> }
> ```

This code stops taking input from device mic and I also get sound in bluetooth headset that it is ready to listen but it doesn't pick any input from device.

Also,

When I am trying to play any audio into bluetooth headset It doesn't work. Here is the code to play audio

> ```
>         do {
>             let output = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute.outputs[0].portType
>             if output == "Receiver" || output == "Speaker"{
>                 try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
>             }
>             else{
>                 try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
>             }
>             print("Voice Out \(output)" )
>         } catch let error as NSError {
>             print("audioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
>             os_log("Error during changing the current audio route: %@"    , log: PollyVoiceViewController.log, type: .error, error)
>         } catch {
>             os_log("Unknown error during changing the current audio route", log: PollyVoiceViewController.log, type: .error)
>         }
>         do {
>             let soundData =  try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
>             self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData)
>             self.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
>             self.audioPlayer?.volume = 3.0
>             self.audioPlayer?.delegate = self
>             self.audioPlayer?.play()
>         } catch let error as NSError {
>             print("Error getting the audio file"+error.description)
>         }
> ```

Comment: Hi, did you solved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is: **BluetoothHFP is not available in `AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement` mode**

[AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessionmodemeasurement)

After you set `try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)`, the `audioSession.availableInputs` is not contain the `BluetoothHFP`.

> This mode is intended for apps that need to minimize the amount of system-supplied signal processing to input and output signals. If recording on devices with more than one built-in microphone, **the primary microphone is used.**

And in the document of [setPreferredInput(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616491-setpreferredinput)

The `AVAudioSessionPortDescription` must be in the `availableInputs` array.

> The value of the inPort parameter must be one of the AVAudioSessionPortDescription objects in the availableInputs array. If this parameter specifies a port that is not already part of the current audio route and the app’s session controls audio routing, this method initiates a route change to use the preferred port.

And it must set up after setting the mode.

> You must set a preferred input port only after setting the audio session’s category and mode and activating the session.

Comment: Apple may have updated. As of now, on iOS 16 (iPhone 11 Pro), under ``measurement`` mode, ``BluetoothHFP`` will show in the list of ``availableInputs`` if a relevant device is connected.